# In wpf, How to enable one child element to true if parent element is enabled to false?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to how to enable one child element to true if parent enability is set to False.
From below example, I want to enable add togglebutton.

```
<StackPanel Margin="10" x:Name="Panel" IsEnabled="False">
            <ToggleButton Content="Add" IsEnabled="True"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Edit"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Delete"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `IsEnabled` to false in a panel, all child elements in that panel are disabled. You cannot selectively enabled child elements in the panel.

You may, however, want to selectively enable child elements in a panel. (E.g. Disable entire panel, then set `IsEnabled=True`, `IsReadOnly=True` on `TextBox` controls so that you can copy text).

One possible solution is to define a new control that inherits from `TextBox` and does not coerce the value of `IsEnabled`.